Measuring a fluid's temperature using video of a drop falling into the fluid
Katie Bouman's PhD thesis begins with the following paragraph:

Watching a raindrop fall into a puddle of water, causing a ring of
expanding ripples, may seem mundane. However, behind this commonplace
phenomenon is a complex process governed by fluid dynamics and its
interaction with light. By understanding these connections we realize
that the water's temperature is encoded in subtle speed differences of
the expanding ripples and the size of the falling water droplet [12].
With the proper models and analysis techniques, we may be able to
extract this seemingly invisible signal and turn a regular camera into
a visual thermometer, without ever interacting with the fluid.

I was wondering if this was purely a thought experiment to illustrate a point, or has anyone ever calculated the physics of it and devised an actual measurement device to measure temperature based on a video. (Citation 12 does not answer this question, it seems to be a generic reference on fluid dynamics.)
